# string compression in c# language

Tags: c#

I have a c program which does the string compression successfully in c language and it's a brute force approach there in C language.for example if input is aabccccdddddddddddaa then output should be a2b1c3d11a2.

I solved this in c language by taking each character and counting number of its occurrences and then printing that character and it's count.

I am trying to convert this to c# language. I am wondering it should be easy to do in the c# language because of so many string and char built in methods.

Is there a way we can do this in c# by using lambda expressions or built in methods of string or char type in very few lines?

My C code is :

```
        char *encode(char *src)
    {     
          int recurringLen;
          char count[MAX_RLEN];
          char *dest;
          int i, j = 0, k;
          int len = strlen(src);

         // _itoa_s(34,c,10);
          /* If all characters in the source string are different, 
            then size of destination string would be twice of input string.
            For example if the src is "abcd", then dest would be "a1b1c1d1"
            For other inputs, size would be less than twice. 
            test for the scenarios where abababababababababababa bcos output here is a16b11.
            aabbbcccd
            */
           dest = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len*2 + 1));


          /* traverse the input string one by one */
          for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
          {

            /* Copy the first occurrence of the new character */
            dest[j++] = src[i];

            /* Count the number of occurrences of the new character */
            recurringLen = 1;     
            while(i + 1 < len && src[i] == src[i+1])
            {
              recurringLen++;
              i++;
            }   

            /* Store rLen in a character array count[] */
            sprintf_s(count, "%d", recurringLen);

            /* Copy the count[] to destination */
            for(k = 0; *(count+k); k++, j++)
            { 
              dest[j] = count[k]; 
            } 
          }  

          /*terminate the destination string */
          dest[j] = '\0';
          return dest;
    }
```

Comment: Show your `C` code and tell people where did you stuck.

Comment: My C code works fine.I just want to convert this into C# and want to to know can it be done more elegantly ?

Comment: Why down vote in this question???

Comment: Read the MSDN documentation of System.String and System.StringBuilder and see if the methods there help you.

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `a2bc4d11a2` instead of `a2bc3d11a2`?

Comment: Actually, according to the comments in the source, it should probably be `a2b1c4d11a2`, no?

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're right. Although that would make the output string longer.

Comment: I have added more information to my answer, changed it so that it matches any character and simplified to use the * repetition operator.

Comment: Added string extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be done Linqy way by writing an extension method `GroupSeqsBy`

```
string input= "aabccccdddddddddddaa";
var s = String.Join("",input.GroupSeqsBy(c => c)
                            .Select(g => g.Key.ToString() + g.Value.Count()));
```

---

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<S, IEnumerable<T>>> GroupSeqsBy<T, S>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, S> keySelector)
{
    List<T> retList = new List<T>();
    S prev = keySelector(list.FirstOrDefault());
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        if (keySelector(item).Equals(prev))
            retList.Add(item);
        else
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<S, IEnumerable<T>>(prev, retList);
            prev = keySelector(item);
            retList = new List<T>();
            retList.Add(item);
        }
    }
    if (retList.Count > 0)
        yield return new KeyValuePair<S, IEnumerable<T>>(prev, retList);
}
```

Comment: You could return `IGrouping` don't you think?

Answer (score 5):

Using regex you can do this (assuming your example has a typo where c3 should be c4)

```
static readonly Regex re = new Regex( @"(.)\1*", RegexOptions.Compiled );               
static void Main()
{
    string result = re.Replace( "aabccccdddddddddddaa", match => match.Value[0] + match.Length.ToString() );                        
    Console.WriteLine( result );
}
```

Output is:

> a2b1c4d11a2

Basically we are searching for any character that repeats 0 or more times, then replacing this with the character followed by the length of the matched string.

Specifically: -

- . is a match on any character (except \n).
- (.) the round brackets make a [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- \1 is a [numbered back-reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx) to that group, basically re-using the already matched character.
- The * is a [repetition operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) saying repeat the match 0 or more times. We could also have used {0,}.

Some useful links are: 
[Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) | [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) | [C# regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) | [C# Match Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) | [C# Regex Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) | [C# back references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx)

If you want this to be an extension of string (not sure if this was a requirement), then:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{ 
    static readonly Regex re = new Regex( @"(.)\1*", RegexOptions.Compiled );                
    public static string Compress(this string theString)
    {
        return re.Replace( theString, match => match.Value[0] + match.Length.ToString() );             
    }
}
```

Use as follows:

```
string theString = "aabccccdddddddddddaa";
string result = theString.Compress();
```

Comment: Can you give little more description ?

Comment: I have added a bit more into, and some links. I have also changed it so that the match is done on any character (.) rather than just word (w) characters as that is what your example does.